# How to update a Future via Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I define a Future: `late Future snapshot;`

I initialize it when a button is pressed:
`setState(() => snapshot = loadData(...))`

I have a FutureBuilder to use the future.

On the other hand, I have a button which updates a value in a ChangeNotifier (from Provider) when pressed. I would like to change my Future called 'snapshot', with this new value as a parameter of loadData(), and rebuild UI. Any idea to do it ?

Comment: Add your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but, First of all, your logic is somehow wrong because you don't need FutureBuilder to initialize snapshot.
Secondly you need to define a nullable variable which is named snapshot like this:`dynamic snapshot`, and you don't need to define variables as future otherwise you can not use them.Then you need a function inside the provider to request Api. Example:

```
class SomeProvider with ChangeNotifier{
dynamic snapshot;

getSnapshots()async{
final res = await Dio().get("https://jsonplaceholder/posts");
snapshot = res.data;
notifyListeners();
}
```

You can use this function inside onPressed function of button and use snapshot in somewhere).

Comment: Ty for your answer. Btw, "you don't need FutureBuilder to initialize snapshot" -> snapshot is initialized outside FutureBuilder

Comment: Happy if it worked for you :)